# Error in ComponentPresentationAssembler on windows 2008 R2 64 bit machine (Tridion 5.3)

Tags: iis-7.5, tridion, tridion-content-delivery

We are using Tridion 5.3 and moving our content Delivery Server from 32 bit Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 R2 64 bit.

We did re install the Content Delivery and publishing working fine but we are getting following error when we are browsing site in browser.

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {8602F9B1-4545-4B0E-BA98-CD927A34DAA9} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {8602F9B1-4545-4B0E-BA98-CD927A34DAA9} failed due to the following
>   error: 80070005.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:

```
Line 27: 
Line 28:     pageTitle = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
Line 29:     cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(PageID, Page);
Line 30: 
Line 31:
```

We did give access to website folder for Network service, IUSR users but no luck.

We have IIS 7.5 in new environment.

Does anyone know what would cause this error?

Comment: This is not a programming question, you would be better off posting it to serverfault (http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/tridion).

Answer (score 5):

Usually errors like:

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8602F9B1-4545-4B0E-BA98-CD927A34DAA9} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

Indicate me that there is an issue with COM security rights which you can set in: `Component Services` -> `Computer` -> `My Computer` -> `Properties` on the `COM Security` tab.

You then Edit the Defaults and add Local & remote access for the IUSR (that is the lazy way of setting it, officially you should find the CLSID in DCOM Config and add the IUSR rights directly on the component, which is more secure of course).

But in this case I'm not sure if it will fix your problem because Tridion R5.3 platform support stops at Windows 2003 SP2, so it might very well be the case that Windows 2008 will never work. At best I can recommend you to also upgrade Tridion to it's latest release (2011 SP1 HR1) for platform support of Windows 2008.

Comment: Thanks Bart, We initially try to find CLSID in DCOM Config but it was not there.. We are raising case to Tridion Support.

Comment: You can raise it, but I'm sure they will tell you it is unsupported, which it is.

Comment: Yup, Tridion 5.3 is unsupported on Windows 2008 R2. It could also be something as simple as your App Pool being set to run on 64 bit, but Tridion 5.3 (.NET) can only run on 32 bits because of the COM dependencies.